# C# How to stop animated gif from continually looping

Tags: c#, winforms, animated-gif

I have an event that gets called when my app uses the internet. The event changes an animated gif composed of 7 frames. How do I make it only loop through the frames only once?

```
        private void trafficSendingActive(object sender, trafficEventArgs e)
        {
            txImage.Image = Properties.Resources.blip;
        }
```

Comment: Won't this work `txImage.Image =(blip);` or maybe you need to move that code to some `OnPaint Event`

Comment: Disabling the txtImage will prevent the gif from being animated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `System.Drawing.ImageAnimator` to start/stop the gif animation

```
// start
System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.Animate(txImage.Image, OnFrameChanged);

// stop
System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.StopAnimate(txImage.Image, OnFrameChanged);

private void OnFrameChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // frame change
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You could always encapsulate the image/gif inside a Picturebox, and when you want the gif to stop, just set the Enabled property of the Picturebox to false.

Just a thought.

Answer (score 6):

You can extract single frame from that `GIF` image (non - animated) when the progress event is done,

```
txImage.Image = Image.FormFile("non-animated-frame-from-gif.jpg");
```

You can use this website to extract frame from gif : http://gif-explode.com/

Answer (score 4):

You can just use `pictureBox.Enabled = false;` if you want to stop the GIF & `pictureBox.Enabled = true;` when you want it to run the GIF.