# Pause a GIF in a form

Tags: c#, picturebox, gif

Just wondering how could you go about pausing a GIF image?
I'm accessing a server and I want a gif image to play when something is happening and if the system has froze I want it to pause.
I have a picturebox with the image attached to it.
Is this possible?

Comment: Please tag as winforms, WPF, or ASP.NET

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647901/c-sharp-how-to-stop-animated-gif-from-continually-looping

Comment: Since you know (as it looks) when the state is changing (from idle in progress and vice versa), regardles of the platform a possible solution would be to have one animated gif and one normal and just change them when appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PictureBox uses the ImageAnimator class to animate a GIF image.  Which has the Stop() method to stop the animation.  Unfortunately it doesn't expose the members you need to tinker with it, you'd have to use ImageAnimator yourself.

If you are not against using Reflection to hack around these restrictions then you could use a back-door.  It is normally a fairly bad idea, but Winforms is in maintenance mode and the odds that PictureBox is ever going to change again are very close to zero.  It looks like this:

```
using System.Reflection;
...

    private static bool IsAnimating(PictureBox box) {
        var fi = box.GetType().GetField("currentlyAnimating",
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        return (bool)fi.GetValue(box);
    }
    private static void Animate(PictureBox box, bool enable) {
        var anim = box.GetType().GetMethod("Animate", 
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] { typeof(bool) }, null);
        anim.Invoke(box, new object[] { enable });
    }
```

This sample button's Click event reliably stopped and started the animation:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Animate(pictureBox1, !IsAnimating(pictureBox1));
    }
```

If you don't care for these kind of hacks then use ImageAnimator yourself.

Comment: This restarts the animation playing from the first frame over again. Is there any way to REALLY pause the animation and resume playing from the frame it was paused?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the desired frame to a bitmap

```
        Image gifImg = ActivscreenLibraries.Resources.throbber_running;
        FrameDimension dimension = new FrameDimension(gifImg.FrameDimensionsList[0]);
        // Number of frames
        int frameCount = gifImg.GetFrameCount(dimension);
        // Return an Image at a certain index
        gifImg.SelectActiveFrame(dimension, 5);
        Bitmap aa = new Bitmap(gifImg);
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromHbitmap(aa.GetHbitmap());
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in comments to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15647901/5198722) Micha has linked you can simple set

```
myPictureBox.Enabled = false;
```

to stop image animation. Set it to `true` to start it again. The is no need for Reflections.

`Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnEnabledChanged` essentially calls `Animate(Enabled)`. See the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PictureBox.cs,dcda9af1adc89f67).

Comment: This will stop the animation, but when you re-enable the box the animation will start from the beginning each time, which looks pretty jarring.