# System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.Animate and System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.StopAnimate explanation

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, lambda

i found this syntax from another article([C# How to stop animated gif from continually looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647901/c-sharp-how-to-stop-animated-gif-from-continually-looping)) but it seems i cant understand it. what is the meaning or purpose of s and e from

```
System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.Animate(txImage.Image, (s,e) => OnFrameChanged(s,e));


// start
System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.Animate(txImage.Image, (s,e) => OnFrameChanged(s,e));

// stop
System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.StopAnimate(txImage.Image, (s, e) => OnFrameChanged(s, e));

private void OnFrameChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// frame change
}
```

or simply can anyone explain this briefly. sorry for being stupid but im really new to programming but i really want to learn thank you

Comment: That's called a lambda expression.  Here, it's unnecessary.

Comment: You should search for the term `Lambda Expression in .NET`, `s` and `e` are arguments of the method encapsulated by the corresponding `delegate`, they can be named differently as you want, for example `sender` instead of `s` and `ev` instead of `e`, ... All the things after `=>` is the code part of the method.

Comment: if you are familiar with `Anonymous Method` in c#2.0 it will be easy for you to understand `Lambda Expression`. if you are not aware of both topics you can refer both of them in MSDN

Comment: tnx for the info's i really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three basic ways in which you can write an event handler.  Unfortunately the author of that code got it pretty wrong by inappropriately mixing them up.  What he should have used is the original C# version 1 way:

```
ImageAnimator.Animate(txImage.Image, OnFrameChanged);
```

Which is quite straight-forward and easy to understand.  Certainly the syntax you should strongly prefer in this case, it makes it very easy to call the StopAnimate() method.  To answer your question, I need to show the other two ways, the ones you should not use.  In C# version 2, an anonymous delegate can be used to write the code for the event handler in-place:

```
ImageAnimator.Animate(txImage.Image, delegate {
    // Put the OnFrameChanged code here...
});
```

In C# version 3, lambda expressions became available to write an event handler in-place:

```
ImageAnimator.Animate(txImage.Image, (s, e) => {
    // Put the OnFrameChanged code here...
});
```

Which is what you asked about.  The (s, e) part of the lambda expression represent the two arguments that are passed to the event handler, s is the *sender*, e is the EventArgs object.  Do note that you don't actually *use* those two arguments in your OnFrameChange code so the lambda syntax is superfluous, the anonymous delegate works just as well.  Albeit that many C# programmers have stopped using them and prefer to use the lambda expression syntax everywhere.  Which is fair.  Even though you don't use the arguments, you must still write them to convince the compiler that your lambda is a proper substitute for the delegate.  Much like you still had to write OnFrameChanged with two arguments to keep the compiler happy.

Understanding lambda expression syntax can be a bit of a speed-bump, any decent introductory book about the C# language will do a better job than I can do to explain it.

Last but not least, you'll find some hackorama code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17546316/17034) to show you how to pause an animation in a PictureBox without having to use the ImageAnimator class at all.  Albeit with some odds that this just adds more questions :)

Comment: wow thanks a lot Mr. Hans Passant i really understand it thank you!

Comment: Mr Hans now that i understand the `.Animate` and `lambada expressions`
how about how can i stop the Gif at a specific frame like if it has 7 frames. if my mouse enter the `picture box` it change its image with gif and stop it on frame 7.

Comment: Just count off the frames in your OnFrameChanged method and don't change the frame when you get to 7.

Comment: so meaning il use the getFrameCount, can you specify a simple syntax

Comment: You'll need to click the Ask Question button to ask another question.

Comment: oh i thought that it would be redundant :) sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Animate and StopAnimate expect "an eventHandler object that specifies the method that is called when the animation frame changes."
You can read this as

```
System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.Animate(txImage.Image, new EventHandler(this.OnFrameChanged))
```