# How to getFrameCount

Tags: c#, winforms, gif

I just have a little problem about the syntax of my code.
here's my code

```
int frames = Properties.Resources.LOGODENTER.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Time);

private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       pictureBox1.Enabled = true;
        pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.LOGODENTER;
        if (frames == 7)
        {
            pictureBox1.Enabled = false;
        }       
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        pictureBox1.Enabled = true;
        pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.LOGOLEAVE1;
        if (frames == 6)
        {
            pictureBox1.Enabled = false;
        }
}
```

Basically what i really want to happen is that when when my pointer enters the control `picturebox1` it change its image with `GIF(LOGODENTER)` and when the mouse is leaving its area it change again its image with `GIF(LOGOLEAVE1)`. I understand imageAnimator.Animate/StopAnimate but  don't know how to use it. But i think you also get what my code logic is.

this is my 2nd article about stopping gif from looping. this is the first [System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.Animate and System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.StopAnimate explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636121/system-drawing-imageanimator-animate-and-system-drawing-imageanimator-stopanimat)

Answer (score 0):

as it seems to me you are doing it all right.
i've used [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQMDsJgMXhE) video to add images to my resources and used a `pictureBox` with the following code:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
  {
     this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
     this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(35, 28);
     this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
     this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 50);
     this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 0;
     this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
     this.pictureBox1.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseLeave);
     this.pictureBox1.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseEnter);
     pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.confirmation;
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.error;

}

private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.confirmation;
}
```

and it worked

let me know if anything is missing